# What is the correct way to push into an array that is a property of an object?

Tags: php

What is the correct way to push into an array that is a property of an object?

Error:

```
Fatal error: Cannot use [] for reading in ... on line ..
```

Code:

```
class StreamResponse 
{
  public  $messages ;

  function __construct($post) 
  {
    $strippost = stripslashes_deep( $_POST );    
    foreach ($strippost['messages'] as $message) 
    {
      $m = json_decode($message, true);
      $this->$messages[] = $m; //<-- This line is the line with the issue
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use the dollar sign before `messages` when you are using `$this`

`$this->messages[] = $m;`